# Why did this happen to my pennine?

Tags: everyday-life, physical-chemistry, food

I went to check on my pasta and found it in a rather odd configuration.

[image: pennine]

(Originally, all the pasta was standing together; the few loose ones there are because I had picked up the pot, semi-drained it, and set it back down before taking this photo.)

It had cooked fully submerged in boiling water on a gas stove for 5–10 minutes. The heat was on medium.

The pot was closed with a lid, though the lid has small openings to allow for draining. There was water around the base of the pot, indicating that it had boiled over.

[image: lid]

All the pasta had been loose and separate when it was dry and I poured it in. After I drained the water, the pasta continued to stand on end, but some light knocking dislodged it.

Comment: This is not really a question about food. That is to say, the fact that the pasta is edible probably has no bearing on the answer. This really is a question about [_self organizing systems_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organization). I don't see an existing tag for that, which is a shame. I don't know how many points one needs to earn the "create new tags" privilege, but apparently it's more points than I have earned.

Comment: Congratulations!  You made a pasta crystal!!!!

Comment: 'Application of the Ising model to culinary arts' - so does it happen with gluten-free pasta?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I am under the impression the "create tags" privillege is available at 1000 pts.

Comment: I think that you need to give more details, if available, about the age and storage conditions of the pre boiled pasta, as "something", beyond the boiling process, is responsible for the "glue" between the strands. No reflection on your food hygiene standards, but the condition of the saucepan may contribute to the outcome.

Comment: @StudyStudy The pasta was bought within the last month and stored in a screw-top jar only ever used for storing dry pasta. It's Canadian wheat pasta. The pot is cleaned via scrubbing and dish detergent between uses and stored in a drawer. To be honest, I think the natural starch of the pasta is enough to account for the gluing effect at the bottom of the pan and/or to each other, but I think the more interesting question is why they stood on their ends.

Comment: My apologies, I've never eaten pasta so I'm not familiar with it's normal degree of "stickiness" and I take your point about the upright stance. I wonder if at any stage, especially at the end of the cooking, did you raise the lid quickly enough to possibly create an up draught.of air/steam which may have initiated a small region of vertical pasta which then propagated a la the self organizing reference above?

Comment: @StudyStudy That's quite a record you've got of no pasta yet :D The draught of air is interesting. I can't remember now if it was like this before draining or not — I noticed it while draining which is why I put it back down. But I was thinking something similar because of the holes in the lid, especially if the water boiled over. Maybe the water, trying to escape through those little holes, created a mini vortex / tunnel that tugged at the pasta and ended up creating a path of least resistance — namely a tube roughly aligned with the direction of the hole.

Comment: My parents were keto,  I'm keto and my kids...well, you get the idea.....my guess earlier was that, because of your description of the pot boiling over, you pulled the lid off faster than you normally do. But your vortex idea is better. Possible a combination of both effects.  The vortices were "primed" but on their own would not have been sufficiently powerful to tilt the gooey  (sorry...:) pasta into a vertical position, but by lifting the lid rapidly enough, you provided a sufficient draught to complete the uprighting process and line the tubes up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have no background of any kind in physics, but having been encouraged in the comments:

I suspect that the boiling over is a good clue. Because this lid has those built-in holes at the side for draining, water tries to escape through there under some pressure. But I expect the small size of the holes means the water creates little vortices like a drain and a pulling force when it's boiling over.

This force would have interacted with the pasta swirling around in the boiling water, and pushed the noodles into a "path of least resistance" by aligning them as a tube with the direction of the holes. But not being enough to lift them, they remained at the bottom of the pot (perhaps as something swirling down a drain remains suspended in the water for longer than you'd expect?).

As for the gluing with starch, it was pretty light, since as we see some fell away with a little jostling. It may just have been partly an effect of their being packed closely enough to stick to each other. But if they did glue a little to the bottom, that's still possible with the above since the pasta comes to a point rather than being a flush cylinder and so water can still get into it while it makes contact with the bottom.

I can think of a caveat to this theory... In the image, you can see that the pasta is not by one of the grooves in the side of the pot. Those grooves are where the holes align when the lid is on properly, which I think it was at the time. So you would probably expect the noodles to be by the groove.

Comment: you could also check the gas stove heating pattern for additional sources of non-uniformities and structure in this system.